# traefik, docker, and SSL: "Error reading configuration file: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to set up a very basic reverse proxy to start some experimentation, but embarrassingly, I can't get even a very simple configuration to work.

In my (otherwise empty) home directory, I have 4 files: docker-compose.yml (defining reverse-proxy), certs.toml and my two certificate files. If I run my reverse-proxy by itself, it generates self-signed certificates and works fine. However, if I try to feed it my actual certificates, it throws the error:

`Cannot start the provider *file.Provider: error reading configuration file: certs.toml - open certs.toml: no such file or directory`

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: "reverse-proxy"
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
      - --providers.file.filename=certs.toml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

certs.toml:

```
[tls.stores.default.defaultCertificate]
  certFile = "<domain>.crt"
  keyFile = "<domain>.key"
```

And the crt (or I could use pem?) and key files are as one would expect.

So, what really basic mistake am I making here? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `certs.toml` is only on your Linux host and not in your container.

You should add it to your container. You should check the the `volumes` section of your `docker-compose.yml`.

Also be carefull of relative vs absolute path in your `docker-compose.yml` (both for the `volumes` and `--providers.file.filename`).

Answer (score 0):

under volumes you can include

```
  `- "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  - "${PWD}/treafik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml "
  - "${PWD}/certs:/certs"`
```

and include the self signed certificate in certs folders in a current working directory.